# Why should I go with reactjs instead of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

The Question might seem/is opinion based, but please understand that I'm an inexperienced developer who is recently introduced to a new term, "react" and unable to decide what to do with it.Please let me give you some more context to it in a "prologue".

I'm a working on a project which is to be "launched" on various platforms like Android, IOS, and as Web Application. A friend of mine suggested me to use React Native and Reactjs instead of working with various languages (Swift, Android Studio and jquery). Please note that I'm not working alone and have team members.

So I'm forced to wonder, "Is react better than jquery?, and that I will be forced to use react, in future, instead of jquery?". Since the web application is still in initial stages of development, Should I switch to react now?

**READ FROM HERE, TO GET TO THE POINT**

Initial findings and my understanding on the topic:-

First reactjs, I have gone through articles and tutorials on it's official website and on various other websites. Some websites call react better in some aspects and few others brand it "superior".My basic understanding is that react is good at handling large number of states (atleast 1000+ complex elements for the difference to be noticeable) when compared to jquery. Then there are few others like immutability,componetization in react to consider but nothing jquery can't work around (I believe).

As for jquery, I know only a bit of jquery and have worked with it in the past, but never too deep. Hence, I wouldn't call myself an expert in it. It offers a large number of plugins that are stable and I can choose from and be sure that there won't be any problems in the very near future.

As I read more on the topics, further conflicted I feel. Hence, preventing me from moving forward with my work and myself. I'm unable to quantify the values of the two technologies. If you can help me understand why or in which case someone would say, "React was an awesome decision." or the same for jquery, it will be greatly appreciated.

**MY OPINIONS ABOUT THE SAID TECHNOLOGIES, IGNORE IF NOT NEEDED**

I'm inclined to go with jquery, since it has been around for about a decade and I'm quite familiar with it and simply because it makes my work easier. I don't think my, or any web application for that matter, would ever need to work with 1000+ elements but I'm still very inexperienced and may fail to see outside "my box".

I would like it if there can be general pointers in the terms of advantages and disadvantages in terms of performance, sustainability of the technologies, etc and not just from my project point of view, as I'm looking do develop myself and my career, ideally,  in either of the two technologies.

**This would also help other beginners like me, who are working towards self development in the field.*
Thank you for your patience, as I realize the question became too big than I intended. Please take your time to reply.*

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-react

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-ok-to-use-React-js-instead-of-jQuery

http://blog.zigomir.com/react.js/jquery/2015/01/11/jquery-versus-react-thinking.html

Comment: If you have never worked with any complex JS library (jquery is simple as dumb) you should learn react before using it in production. Otherwise you will fail project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very different end goals. To give a very short answer:

jQuery is about manipulating the DOM and use other browser APIs to do things with it (change text, colour, send requests to a server, load images).

React is about declaring the way something should render, giving it some data and poof, when the data changes, it renders those changes.